# In bash, how to make a comparison and assign the boolean result to a variable

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I am doing a string comparison between a variable and a constant. The result of the comparison, either `true` or `false`, is assigned to another variable.

```
LABEL=$("${INPUT}" == "flag");
```

However, I am failing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `expr`:

```
INPUT='flag'
LABEL=$(expr "${INPUT}" == "flag")
echo "$LABEL"
1

INPUT='flab'
LABEL=$(expr "${INPUT}" == "flag")
echo "$LABEL"
0
```

Comment: Is it possible that the evaluation returns `true`/`false` instead of `0`/`1`?

Comment: No that will require little longer version as this: `[[ "$INPUT" == "flag" ]] && LABEL=true || LABEL=false`

Comment: Should it be `LABEL=$(expr "${INPUT}" = "flag")`?
The double equals doesn't work for me

Comment: This will return an error, or unexpected results if `$INPUT` (or `"flag"`) contains any `expr` expressions such as `(`, `+`, `substr`, [and others](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expr).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier and can cover more test cases. For you can get more details about string comparisons and test cases via 'man test'. Here's a pretty basic sample.

```
if [ "${INPUT}" == "flag" ]; then
   LABEL=${INPUT}
fi

echo ${LABEL}
```

Comment: This straight up doesn't work for cases where the comparison is false though. It also defeats the whole point of the question which is to avoid the noobish commonplace if then true else false assignment